# Working with getElementById( x ).onclick = someFunction

Tags: javascript, checkbox, getelementbyid

I thought for long how to define the question but i couldn't, i need to explain the code.

I want to make a simple organizer in JavaScript. You enter the task and click on the button "add to the list" and a script makes a checkbox with paragraph that contains the task's text. The second part is the disabling the checkbox, and striking through that tasks text when you click on it. I tried to do that by giving every checkbox i create a function (destroyIt() that gets element by id and than disables it, but it works only for the last checkbox added to the page. I am looking at this code for long time and i can't see what is wrong. Please help. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>

    <style id="stil">
        .over{
            text-decoration:line-through;
        }
    </style>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        var numberOfTasks=1;

        function insertNew(){
            tekst = document.getElementById("zadatak").value;
            if(tekst.length>0){
                var idEl= "check"+numberOfTasks;

                document.getElementById("ispis").innerHTML+="<input type='checkbox' id='check"+numberOfTasks+"'> "+"<span class='"+idEl+"'>"+tekst+"</span> <br/>";

                document.getElementById(idEl).onclick= function(){ destroyIt(idEl); };

                numberOfTasks++;
            }
        }       
        function destroyIt(idEl){
            document.getElementById(idEl).disabled=true;
            document.getElementById("stil").innerHTML+= "."+idEl+"{text-decoration:line-through;}";
            alert(idEl+"{text-decoration:line-through;}");
        }


    </script>
</head>

<body>
    Tasks for: <span id="date"> </span>

    <script>
        var date= new Date();
        document.getElementById("date").innerHTML= ""+ date.getDay() +"." +date.getMonth() +"." +date.getFullYear();
    </script>

    <br/> <br/>
    New task: <input type="text" id="zadatak"> <button onclick="insertNew()"> add to the list </button>

    <button onclick="provera()">Provera</button>
    <p id="ispis"> </p>
</body>
```

Comment: is this your full code?

Comment: I'd suggest putting together a simple [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, demo. Stripping everything down to the *minimum* amount of code necessary to reproduce your problem. (If you've not used it before, here's the "[how to](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/)," from the documentation.) Incidentally, if all you're trying to do is change the presentation, then: `input:checked + span { text-decoration: line-through; }` (Or: `input[disabled] + span`)

Comment: You're trying to change the style by editing the stylesheet? I think maybe some basic tutorials will be helpful for you.

Comment: @Mritunjay Yes, code window here cut off just </html>

Comment: ...but the problem is your use of `.innerHTML += "...new content..."` It destroys the old elements and their event handlers. I don't like adding new elements with HTML markup, but if you insist on it, use `.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "...new content...)`.

Comment: @cookiemonster The main task is to disable the clicked checkbox, I am trying to understand the DOM tree and giving events according functions. Sorry for my english

Comment: Don't change the `<style>` element. Add the `over` class to the element when you disable it.

Comment: Instead of using `innerHTML`, create the element with `createElement`, and add it with `appendChild`.

Comment: @DavidThomas I will see a how to for JS Fiddle, I never saw it, thank you for mentioning.

Comment: @Barmar I am going to try that. I didn't know that innerHTML destroys previous event handlers. Thanks

Comment: It's writing the HTML fresh from the string you assign. There are no handlers in a string of HTML.

Comment: @Barmar: Except that he's doing a DOM selection and assigning the handler after the `.innerHTML` manipulation. The problem is that he's destroying the old content, which had previously received the event handler.

Comment: That's my point. There are no handlers when he assigns `.innerHTML`. There's a handler after that because he adds a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you do `.innerHTML += "..."`, it destroys the existing nodes and their event handlers, and replaces them with new, clean nodes. For this and other reasons, you should almost never use `+=` after `.innerHTML`.

A better way to insert new content from HTML markup is to use `.insertAdjacentHTML()` instead. The first argument describes the position relative to the element on which it was invoked, and the second argument is the new content.

So your code with `.insertAdjacentHTML()` would look like this:

```
function insertNew(){
    tekst = document.getElementById("zadatak").value;
    if(tekst.length>0){
        var idEl= "check"+numberOfTasks;

        document.getElementById("ispis")
                .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd", "<input type='checkbox' id='check"+numberOfTasks+"'> "+"<span class='"+idEl+"'>"+tekst+"</span> <br/>");

        document.getElementById(idEl).onclick= function(){ destroyIt(idEl); };

        numberOfTasks++;
    }
}
```

---

Furthermore, you can modify the `destroyIt` function to operate on its `this` value, which will give you the `input` element that has the handler. You can then use its `.id` to get the class of the `span`, or you can just traverse to the next element.

Also, you shouldn't modify the style sheet to hide the element. Just add a class or a direct style property.

So in the above function, this:

```
document.getElementById(idEl).onclick= function(){ destroyIt(idEl); };
```

becomes this:

```
document.getElementById(idEl).onclick= destroyIt;
```

And then the `destroyIt` function becomes this:

```
function destroyIt(){
    var span = this.nextElementSibling;
    this.disabled=true;
    span.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
}
```

The `.nextElementSibling` will need to be patched in IE8, but this is just for simple demonstration.

Comment: Not a criticism, but is there a reason you chose to use `insertAdjacentHTML()` rather than `.appendChild()`, other than the former lets you use the same string of HTML (rather than creating/appending nodes)?

Comment: Thank you. And is it better to use insertAdjacentHTML or createElement and appendChild or is it the same?

Comment: @DavidThomas: That's the only reason. I personally prefer DOM creation methods, but since he was using HTML, I thought I'd provide the better way to work with HTML.

Comment: @user1932153: It's a matter of preference, but usually `HTML` manipulation will be a little slower since it requires parsing the markup in order to do the creation. Using `.createElement/appendChild` is a purer solution IMO.